Vector arrow and subscript
Compare the two cases below. In the first case, the arrow is too long, in the second one the subscript is too far apart. Is it possible to have the first one but with shorter vector arrow?
\documentclass[border=2pc]
{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[e]{esvect}
\begin{document}
$\vv{F_{P_x}}$

$\vv{F}_{P_x}$
\end{document}



Not that it helps you, but as far as I remember we needed to adapt something deep down to be able to have this in ConTeXt. That formula was typeset with \m {\vec {F} __ {P __ x}}

We need to place a vector arrow of fixed length above F_P_x regardless of the length of the equation. Here is a potential solution :
The \overset command positions the arrow (created with \vv) above the expression F_P_x.
The \makebox[Xpt]{} generates an empty horizontal box of X points, defining the length of the arrow regardless of the underlying text.
\documentclass[border=2pc]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\vv{\makebox[12pt]{}}}{F_{P_x}}%
~\text{or}~%
\overset{\vv{\makebox[9pt]{}}}{F_{P_x}}%
$
\end{document}



In fact, I think that the arrow is a little high in vertical position.

Use \mathrlap from mathtools to fool the above arrow and \phantom to compensate the lost space.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[e]{esvect}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & \vv{F_{P_x}} aaa \\
  & \vv{F_{P_{\mathrlap{x}}}}\phantom{\scriptscriptstyle x} aaa
\end{align*}
\end{document}


